# Can I request access to additional Facebook user info *optionally*?

Tags: facebook

When the users sign up to my website with Facebook, I'd like to request additional information, but I can cope if they refuse.

What I don't want to do is to offer the user a "take it or leave it" dialog, where they either give me all that info, or can't sign up with Facebook at all.

Is there any way to make this extra info optional and let the user choose if they want to share it? I mean information such as their interests and likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered here

[Facebook developer: making a permission optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928670/facebook-developer-making-a-permission-optional)

Note that the answer is specifically for a .NET application but it indicates that the best way to do this is to request specific permissions when they are signing up to your application and then ask them for additional "optional" permissions later. Look in the FB documentation on how to use Extended Permissions here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/